# ePub submission issue in NookPress.com

Tags: epub, submission, nook

After uploading an ePub file to NookPress.com,an error appeared which said
"An Error Occurred Processing Content
FATAL:referenced resource missing in the package"

I have checked my HTMLs,Content.opf & ncx files and found no such problem in data,
I have tested my ePub file with ePub checker,It is showing nothing wrong with the ePub file created by me.
If anyone faced the same issue & would able to resolve it,Do let me know,I have been tangling with this problem since long.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrestled with this same problem for most of a day. Finally, I submitted my EPUB file to EPUB Validator (http://validator.idpf.org/), which will give you more information about what the problem is exactly. In my case, I did not put "http://" in front of my website in an anchor tag. I had some other issues, too, but these were mainly warnings that I went ahead and stamped out.

Hopefully, this will help you out and get you over the hump.